# Sending JSON Post with Body using Android Volley

Tags: android, json, post, android-volley

I am trying to send a JSON Post request using Android Volley library but I dont seem to get the body of the json right and I get undefined body parameters on my web server. I need the json's parameters body to be a single object "name=someVal&comment=someOtherVal". name and comment are the keys and someVal and someOtherVal are the values.

```
String spreadsheetID = "1111111-11111N92RT9h-11111111111111111111111111111";
String url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/" + spreadsheetID + "/exec";
// Instantiate the RequestQueue.
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

// Request a string response from the provided URL.
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
        url, null,
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
    Log.d("JSONPost", response.toString());
    //pDialog.hide();
}
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        VolleyLog.d("JSONPost", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
        //pDialog.hide();
    }
}) {

    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("name=someVal&comment=someOtherVal");
        //params.put("comment", "someOtherVal");
        return params;
    }
};
// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
queue.add(jsonObjReq);
```

}

I also tried this in the above code but no luck:

```
params.put("comment", "someOtherVal");
params.put("name", "someVal");
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try to put

```
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
params.put("comment", "someOtherVal");
params.put("name", "someVal");
```

before JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq ... and change the null value by

```
new JsonObject(params)
```

so your code will be

```
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("comment", "someOtherVal");
    params.put("name", "someVal");

JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
        url, new JsonObject(params),
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
    Log.d("JSONPost", response.toString());
    //pDialog.hide();
}
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        VolleyLog.d("JSONPost", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
        //pDialog.hide();
    }
})
```

Comment: Still no luck. Thanks though.

Comment: I had that problem the only solution i tried is changing the library, i used retrofit instead of volley and everything goes right

Comment: I actuary tried with URL connection library and it works but lets leave it as other people may run into the same problem.

Comment: this example failed.

Answer (score 2):

It seems Google Spreadsheet was preferring this format:

```
String spreadsheetID = "111111-111111111D746wspoleBbRN92RT9h-111111";
        String url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/" + spreadsheetID + "/exec";
        // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                //
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                //
            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("name","userAccount.getUsername()");
                params.put("comment","userAccount.getPassword()");
                return params;
            }

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                return params;
            }
        };
        queue.add(sr);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to send a JSON POST then you should dump the http.HEADERS and the http.WIRE and you should probably see ....

```
 "Content-Type: application/json"   // among headers
...
   {"name":"someVal","comment":"someOtherVal"}   // in the POST.body
```

Find out how to log header and log wire in Volley....

Think about testing a POST using CURL on the CLI where adding the -v switch will show you the details. Then , what works in curl you move that verbatim to your android, http client and it will work.

Comment: android WIRE , HEADER logging session example using non-volley client with full logging  http://pastebin.com/7eU9GUKV

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, I am sending a request to an Express server which uses express.json(). The object I am sending in the body is called user and looks like this:

```
{ 
   String: username;
   String: password; 
}
```

```
 RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
 
 // user object that we need to send
 JSONObject userJson = new JSONObject();
 // body of the request
 JSONObject body = new JSONObject();

 try {
    // Put user attributes in a JSONObject
    userJson.put("username", "username value");
    userJson.put("password", "password value");
    // Put user JSONObject inside of another JSONObject which will be the body of the request     
    body.put("user", userJson);
 } catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
 }

JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
                    Request.Method.POST, 
                    url, 
                    body,
                    response -> {
                        // Handle response
                        
                    }, e -> {
                        // handle error
                    }
);

 queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```